# Copying data in Google sheet using dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have been trying to copy data from Sheet "Main" to Sheets (Completed, Pending, Hold) based on selection from dropdown in column 6 named (Status) in Main Sheet.

Column 6 DropDown List (Completed, Pending, Main)

Once a specific record has been changed it copies the record to its specific sheet without deleting the record from the Main sheet.

So far I have got this from elsewhere, however this does not seem to work, can someone please help.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:4

```
function onEdit(event) {
    
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    
If(s.getName() == "Main" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Completed"); {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
    
If(s.getName() == "Main" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Pending"); {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pending");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
    
If(s.getName() == "Main" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Hold"); {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hold");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `I have data in "Setup" Sheet in Google Sheet in B3:D3 with Checkbox in F Column & I3:K3 with Checkbox in M column.` and `"Active" sheet Ref Cell to move data is C3:E3 & O3:Q3`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel are not the same, and they have differences in functionality between them. If you're using one, tags for the other do not apply. Please use only tags that are actually applicable to your post. Tag spamming is highly frowned upon here, and is a quick way to get your post downvoted and/or closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should be used properly. For more information, see the [help].

Comment: I just need the values from the source sheet "Setup" to move to destination Sheet "Active" when the checkbox have been clicked in "Setup" sheet, i do not want the checkbox to be moved to Active Sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike - would you be able to help now that I have made it more clear?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. By the way, about the error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')` of your script, I guess that the reason for your issue is due to that you directly run the script without the event object. If you want to directly run the script, please replace `event.source` to `ss` and test it again. But, I'm not sure this modification is a direct solution because I cannot know your Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the “Active” tab, cell `C3` put:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   FILTER(Setup!B3:D,Setup!F3:F))
```

And in the “Active” tab, cell `O3` put:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   FILTER(Setup!I3:K,Setup!M3:M))
```

A checked checkbox is interpreted as “TRUE” so basically these formulas look at columns with the checkboxes and if check return the values in the specified cells next to them.

If you want to make it cleaner you can also wrap each of them in an IFNA or IFERROR function to avoid showing an error when nothing is checked.

Comment: This does not work as I have just pasted code from YT videos, the number of columns need to be defined in this case

Comment: Ahh I see, the entire question has changed since I submitted this answer—disregard! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  const v = e.value
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: source name = "+src.getName()+", row = "+r.rowStart + ", column = "+r.columnStart+", value = "+v)
  
  if (src.getName() != "New" || r.columnStart != 6 || r.rowStart == 1 || v != "TRUE") return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Active");
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: source range = "+src.getRange(r.rowStart,2,1,3).getA1Notation()+" destination range = "+dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,3).getA1Notation())
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,3).copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,2,));
}
```

---

**Notes**

- `r.columnStart != 6` - tests for an edit in Column F
- `v != "TRUE"` - tests for value of "TRUE" (i.e. checkbox is checked)
- `.copyTo` - copies the data rather than moves it.